# How many threads should I spawn for maximum performance?

Tags: multithreading, performance, rust

I am writing a Rust script that needs to brute force the solution to some calculation and is likely to run 2^80 times. That is a lot! I am trying to make it run as fast as possible and thus want to divide the burden to multiple threads. However if I understand correctly this only accelerates my script if the threads actually run on different cores, otherwise they will not truly run simultaneously but switch between one another when running..

How can I make sure they use different cores, and how can I know that no more cores are available?

Comment: If this computation was embarrassingly parallel and you ran it on 1024 cores, each core would still have to do 2^70 runs. If you could do 1 Billion runs in a second, your program would finish after 37,436 years (barring any arithmetic errors on my part).

Comment: Use a library like [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon), that already gives you the optimal parallelism for your system. But yes, 2^80 is already close to cryptographically safe against brute-force attacks, so yes, you won't simply 'solve' this problem with parallelism :D

Comment: indeed! thanks for the perspective!

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: Use [`std::thread::available_parallelism`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.available_parallelism.html) (or alternatively the [num-cpus](https://docs.rs/num_cpus/latest/num_cpus/) crate) to know how many threads to run and let your OS handle the rest.

---

Typically when you create a thread, the OS thread scheduler is given free liberty to decide where and when those threads execute, however it will do so in a way that best takes advantage of CPU resources. So of course if you use less threads than the system has available, you are potentially missing out on performance. If you use more than the number of available threads, that's not particularly a problem since the thread scheduler will try its best to balance the threads that have work to do, but more than the available threads would be a mall waste of memory, OS resources, and context-switches. Creating your threads to match the number of logical CPU cores on your system is the sweetspot, and the above function will get that.

You *could* tell the OS exactly which cores to run which threads by setting their [affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity), however that isn't really advisable since it wouldn't particularly make anything faster unless you start really configuring your kernel or are really taking advantage of your NUMA nodes.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the parallelism thread returned by the method you suggested, strictly returns thread that will truly run in parallel right? As in how many new cores can be used?

Comment: @FreddyC you can read the documentation if you're unsure since there may be some system configurations that cause it to report incorrectly what is available to you, but roughly, yes.